# List focus on a particular item in that list dynamically

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment, focusmanager

In my project i have a `ListView` for handling the list of a product. In that i have a list of 100 Items in that List view. Each and Every time i have been seeing the first row of the `ListView`..

If i need to see the data in the `ListView` Means, i need to scroll down, Can i focus directly to a particular item by any function by passing the position(ID) of the `ListView`..

For Example this is my `ListView` that contains 11 items in it..

[image]

I'm seeing every time the `ListView` as the following,..

[image]

And my try is, If i give the `ListView` position as `ID=5` means, can i get the Focus of the `ListView` as follow, in the opening itself...

[image]

Can we get this by `ListFragment` method or anything else?
Suggest me for the Best..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, use `setselection`

```
listview.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Will you suggest an answer for Edited Question?

Comment: After set your `Adapter` grid.setAdapter(sca);. and then use listview.setSelection(position). try this

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about `ListFragment` but in `listview`, you can use `listview.setSelection(position);`

This method will help you to achieve this 
for example: `listview.setSelection(5);`